# How to get current time in T07:07:45-0500 format

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I want to get the current time in `T07:07:45-0500` format.

I have try like this:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
String currentTime = currentDate.ToString("'T'HH':'mm':'ssK");
Console.WriteLine("DOB ==> " + dateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + currentTime);
```

But the result is `1986-07-11T07:07:45-05:00`

I want result like `1986-07-11T07:07:45-0500`

Is there any way to get the current time in `T07:07:45-0500` format.

Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the .NET [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allow that format. You could use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project easily enough, using `DateTimeOffset.Now` if you want the system default time zone to be applied. (It can be done explicitly

For example:

```
var odt = OffsetDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now);
var pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sso<+HH:mm>");
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Format(odt));
```

As noted in comments, you're currently doing something very odd in terms of combining the values. If you really want to do that, I would personally create an appropriate `OffsetDateTime` like this:

```
LocalDate dateOfBirth = ...; // Wherever that comes from
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now);
OffsetDateTime mixture = dateOfBirth.At(now.LocalTime).WithOffset(now.Offset);
var pattern = ...; // as before
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Format(mixture));
```

That makes it clearer *how* you're combining the values.

Comment: I will get the date of birth from the user and i will send to server. I have to send the current time zone to the server. If I am in Istanbul I have to send it's time zone. If I am in US i have to sent it's time zone. I have to send like, Date of birth + current date with time zone. That's why I am using different date.

Comment: You both people give a quick and valuable response for all the question :-) :-) .. Thank you..

Comment: @Vijay: What is this value meant to represent though? "The current time of day in a particular time zone, on the birth date of someone who might have been born in a different zone" isn't very meaningful, IMO. You've basically got two separate values - it would be better to *keep* them separate. Also note that what you've got at the moment isn't a time zone - it's the offset from UTC at a particular point in time. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @Vijay: Odd. I'll update my answer with more details of doing this in Noda Time then.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I *think* the representation of an offset depends on how your `CurrentCulture` represents [UTC Offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value. It might be the formats as `-05:00`, `-0500`, or simply -`05`.</strike>

Based on comments, looks like UTC Offset format is hard-coded and it doesn't depends on any culture.

You should clearly find the last index of `:` character and replace it with empty string. I don't think there is another solution for this in .NET Framework.

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
String currentTime = currentDate.ToString("'T'HH':'mm':'ssK");
currentTime = currentTime.Remove(currentTime.LastIndexOf(":"), 1);
```

Comment: I don't *think* that offset formats are controlled by DateTimeFormatInfo.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmm.. Might be.. But where this `:` characters comes from? I almost think this comes from `TimeSeparator` property based `CurrentCulture`. I honestly couldn't find anything related on documentation.

Comment: I believe it's just a hard-coded part of the formatting of UTC offsets. It *may* use TimeSeparator, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess you are right. `bn-BD` culture has `.` as a `TimeSeparator` but it still prints offset value in `-05:00` format.

Comment: You both people give a quick and valuable response for all the question :-) :-) .. Thank you..